# Why doesn't Python give the option to define statically typed variables?

Tags: python, variables

My understanding is that dynamic typing slows down the interpreter because lookups cannot be be reduced to static function addresses.

Here's the thing: with most variables, you know that they're never going to change type. Position tuples will stay as tuples, response strings will remain as strings, and almost all dictionaries will remain as dictionaries.

So, why doesn't python give the option to define statically typed variables, in order to improve performance? Something like `static type x = 'hello'` or `string x = 'hello'`. What are the drawbacks?

If the reason this can't be done is due to structural limitations within Python, what are those limitations and are they necessarily deal-breakers?

Comment: Isn't this the point of type hints?

Comment: This is my biggest gripe with dynamically typed languages.

Comment: My understanding is that type hints don't actually set the type of anything, they're just for people reading the code

Comment: That's a lot more complicated than you might think, and most of the benefits are subsumed by a JIT implementation like PyPy.

Comment: That's kind of what Cython does, as well.

Comment: With the use of [mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/), type hinting annotations can be enforce.  Naturally this requires your entire build toolchain make use of that to derive maximum benefits, but even then the benefits end at where the code calls a function that does not have anything annotated.

Comment: Talk to me about how you would like this "static typing" to work? Would you like to first compile part of your program, and then run the rest dynamically? Do you want the static types to be run as dynamic types until you are ready to run the progam at which point you must compile? I'm just seeing a lot of issues with this.

Comment: Adding gradual typing to dynamic languages is an open research problem. How exactly do you expect us to answer it?

Comment: @d_kennetz I think it's more giving hints to the compiler to improve runtime speed rather than any sort of type safety. Or perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Jared Smith From wikipedia: "Gradual typing can easily be integrated into the type system of an object-oriented language that already uses the subsumption rule to allow implicit up-casts with respect to subtyping." This is a little bit over my head. Why can't python implement this?

Comment: @alec_a because it's not compiled ahead of time? JIT compilation will get you 90% of the benefits anyways, one other commenter already mentioned this. I do know that the Racket folks have spent an awful lot of research time on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding static typing would be a fundamental change of the Python3 language. See [Python.org answer](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#non-goals) on static types. Recent updates have added the ability to specify type hints. As far as improving performance, Python3 already has a very well-tuned hash table to help prevent the lookups from slowing down the interpreter.